# What is a better way to classify text using word2vec?

Tags: classification, natural-language, word2vec

I am using `word2vec` to classify documents into various categories. Let's say we have a document:

> Thousands of people with student loan debt will have their debt canceled or receive a one-time check as part of a multistate settlement with one of the nation's largest student loan servicers.

And 6 categories:

- health
- sports
- science
- entertainment
- politics
- finance

With the above data, current approach goes like following:

1. Extract nouns from the document. (`thousands` `people` `student` `loan` `debt` `settlement` ...)
2. For each category, calculate word similarity (using `word2vec`) with every noun and sum similarity values.
3. Select the category that has the highest sum value as the "topic" of the document. (result would be `finance`)

Tested this approach for 50 documents and articles, but accuracy was like 60%. I suspect that this is because the algorithm is too naive - what would be a better way to classify a document using word similarity method like `word2vec`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Word2vec only creates vector representations of words, full stop. It is not a classifier.

If you want to classify the text documents, you'll need to choose a way to represent your sequence of word2vec word vectors to a classification algorithm.

- One option is to compute summary vectors (element-wise mean, max, min, etc.) from the word2vec vectors. These summaries are useful because they create a fixed-length representation of the documents that can be used in a standard classifier (SVM, random forest, etc).
- More ornate methods include using recurrent neural networks or transformer networks applied to the *sequence* of word vectors within each document.